# How do the bacteria producing bacteriocins protect themselves from it?

Tags: cell-biology, microbiology, bacteriology

Whenever there is Col plasmid in a bacteria it will produce bacteriocins which will kill other bacteria around it. Why will the bacteriocin not kill the bacteria which has produced it? How does the Col plasmid also help protect the bacteria from its own bacteriocin?

Comment: Keywords: colicin, immunity, operon, genes, proteins, mechanism.